# How to set a Database Connection for all the Form in MDI?

Tags: vb6

I am Using MDI Form, In all the Form I need the database Connection, How to give connection is active for all the forms.

I want to write a common connection for all. Then I will call the connection for the forms whenever I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MDI Form create a module level variable to hold the connection:

```
Private m_Conn as ADODB.Connection
```

Create a public property getter in the MDI Form:

```
Public Property Get CurrentConnection() as ADODB.Connection
     Set CurrentConnection = m_Conn
End Property
```

From your Child form, to get the MDI Form's connection (assuming MDI Form is named MainForm):

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection

Set oConn = MainForm.CurrentConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define the connection object in **Module** and use it anywhere.